# Flutter, visibility configuration of AndroidManifest.xml for API >= 30

Tags: android, flutter, uri, android-manifest

I'm using `uri_launcher` package to open a phone call and SMS app. To check if it's possible to launch some URI package docs state this:

**On Android (from API 30), [canLaunch] will return `false` when the required
/// visibility configuration is not provided in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
/// For more information see the [Managing package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility)
/// article in the Android docs.**

I've tried just launching some websites and phone numbers and it works just fine (without calling the `canLaunch()`).

What do I need to add to `AndroidManifest.xml` to make this work ?
I've tried with `<query>` didn't work, also the  `<grant-uri-permission>` didn't work. Function is stil returning `false`.

Is it okay if I just launch the URI ? What are the downsides of that ?

Answer (score 8):

You can solve this issue by adding the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Comment: Solved the issue here! Thk!